# NPM outdated command not showing full list

Tags: npm, npm-cli, npm-outdated

When I do on my terminal:
`npm outdated -g`
I get a list of global packages that have updates available, and that's fine:

```
Package              Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
create-next-app       10.0.3  10.0.4  10.0.4  global
eslint-plugin-react   7.21.5  7.22.0  7.22.0  global
firebase-tools         9.0.1   9.1.0   9.1.0  global
```

After I installed all of them, I wanted to make sure that I got all the packages updated, so I hit again, the same command, but accidentally hit `npm outdated -g\`. This time I got a package that not listed before:

```
Package                 Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
eslint-plugin-flowtype    3.9.1  3.13.0   5.2.0  global
```

I hit again `npm outdated -g` and got no result, and repeated with backslash and got this package.
I checked [this](https://github.com/npm/npmconf/blob/master/config-defs.js#L405) and didn't see anything related. Does anyone know what's the issue? Of course I can see that this `eslint-plugin-flowtype` package have breaking changes (3.x vs 5.x), but how is it not displayed in the original `npm outdated -g` command?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is not programming related. You ought to ask at other fora.

Comment: Well, I think it is.

Comment: So where exactly is the code that is not performing as expected. Command line issues pulling down packages is *not* programming.

Comment: npm cli commands related to programming. You can see tons of questions in SO related theses commands. Search 'npm command'. I suggest you remove the close vote.

Comment: Then show  the code you are having problems with.

Comment: This community is not about bugs only, but to understand processes, and commands, and things related to programming. I would appreciate if you would stop right here. Happy new year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-outdated#depth), `npm outdated` defaults to a depth of 0, so unless you override that, you'll always be seeing only top-level dependencies that are outdated. You can run something like `npm outdated --depth 9999` to see all.

Comment: Didn't know that. So If I hit `-g\\` it's the same behavior, apparently. Or did I found a bug in their CLI?

Comment: Perhaps, when I run it with -g\ I don't get anything, so might be a bug

Comment: run with '-g\', not '\g'

Comment: Sorry was a typo, that's how I ran it :)

Comment: Welcome to my LinkedIn:)

Comment: `npm outdated` doesn't look for "outdated"/latest packages and the --depth won't help here. The npm command is useless.